# Data conversion and loss data errors in SSIS 2012

Tags: t-sql, csv, ssis, sql-server-2012, dataflowtask

```
Report.csv
Date             Website               Emp      EmpID           EmployeeHireDate    Skill   ATTEMP1(secs)   ATTEMP2(secs)
2/4/2014 0:00    Chicago               TV        767373         8/18/2013 0:00      DANCE    1858.166667    1858.166667
```

Table

```
Create table report(
date [datetime] NULL,
website [varchar](30) NULL, 
emp [varchar](30) NULL,
empID [int] NULL,
EmployeeHireDate [datetime] NULL,
Skill [varchar](15) NULL,
ATTEMP1secs float null,
ATTEMP2secs float null,)
```

I am using SSIS Package to transfer data from CSV to my table. But `empID,ATTEMP1secs,ATTEMP2secs` is creating problems.

I created table according to data types in CSV file but it showing me error.

> The column status returned was: "The value could not be converted because of a potential loss of data.".

Comment: Did you try creating from SSIS Import and Export wizard and check and see what did you wrong...It should be a good start to do...Don't forget to turn the Run64bitRuntime to False..

Comment: Did you check if the data lenght is more than 30?